# Is it possible to print different foils on one area?

Tags: print-design, print-production

I have turned to this forum to see if someone could hopefully point me in the right direction.

I have had a graphic designer create a double-sided label my business requires. Almost think of it like a business card, it is rectangular in shape, but smaller.

My design has three different foil colours (1 foiling color on the back and 2 foiling colors on the front).

My question is, can you print different foils on one area? All completed works I see online tend to have only one foil color.

Secondly, if this is possible, can someone point me in the direction of a business who can accommodate such a need? I've been in contact with several here in Australia with no luck. I would like to know if someone can recommend an online place that would be able to do this.

To be clear, by different foil color on one area, I mean, the corner of the label requires one color foil and then on a separate part of the label, a different foil color is required.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, by different foil color on one area, i mean, the corner of the label requires one color foil and then on a separate part of the label, a different foil color is required.

Comment: I think this is something you would ultimately need to ask your printer about.  I have seen multi colour foil work. There's an example shown here at around 1:22 [on this video](https://youtu.be/5NPdVsxmiHs?t=82). As for double sided, that's further complexity. Again ask your printer. However since foils are printed using dies to stamp the foil, there's a possibility that stamping the back will affect the finish on the front. The company featured in the video is in the UK, so not sure how useful that will be for you. Their details are in the video description.

Comment: Have you looked into cold foiling? What it does is foil areas and then print over the foil so while it's not quite as shiny as hot foiling, you can put as many colors as you want.

Comment: Why, after talking to several vendors, you've had no luck? They can't do it for what reasons? Or they don't have the capability? Multi-color stamping is no problem and stamping on 2 sides is possible with the right weight of stock. But considering the print run and the number of dies needed, it can get expensive...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. You will need to find an old school shop with a letter or platten press, something like a Heidelberg WindMill with a hot foil stamping attachment. You will have to have specialty dies made and depending on the experience of the operator you may have to run it through three times.

I have seen business cards with five foils on the front and three on the back.

Here is a video to give you an idea of the kind of machine I am talking about. You can see by changing the color and position of the foil ribbon and a different die it can be made as complex as desired.

[Heidelberg WindMill with Hot Foil attachment](https://youtu.be/GldqSS-GpFc)

There are a number of options using varnishes, but they do not compare in quality or precision.